# Upgrade failed Azure AKS from 1.8.1 to 1.8.6

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

Im trying to upgrade my Azure AKS cluster from version 1.8.1 to 1.8.6.

**Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 09312a25-04f3-4e35-8f79-6b2337bb7f19. Operation failed with status: 200. Details: Resource state Failed**

The output of command `az aks upgrade --name myaks --resource-group myresourcegr --kubernetes-version 1.8.6`

More output `az aks show --name myaks --resource-group myresourcegr --output table`

```
    Name     Location    ResourceGroup    KubernetesVersion    ProvisioningState    Fqdn
    -------  ----------  ---------------  -------------------  -------------------  -----------------------------------------
    myaks  westeurope  myresourcegr             1.8.6                Failed               myaks-81cf39b1.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io
```

Retrying the upgrade action I get always the same error

**Edit**

Output of command `az aks get-versions -g myresourcegr -n myaks`

```
{
  "agentPoolProfiles": [
    {
      "kubernetesVersion": "1.8.6",
      "name": null,
      "osType": "Linux",
      "upgrades": [
        "1.8.6"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "controlPlaneProfile": {
    "kubernetesVersion": "1.8.6",
    "name": null,
    "osType": "Linux",
    "upgrades": [
      "1.8.6"
    ]
  },
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxx-98ec-4db6-bfed-946d93a62a7c/resourcegroups/myresourcegr/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/myaks/upgradeprofiles/default",
  "name": "default",
  "resourceGroup": "myresourcegr",
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/upgradeprofiles"
}
```

Comment: Could you run this command `az aks get-versions -g jasonaks -n myk8scluster`?

Comment: Edited with the output ```az aks get-versions -g myresourcegr -n myaks```

Comment: Solved, problem with the quotas of my subscription.

Comment: @Pacolotero can you please assist me with this issue if you can assume what can be an issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66008830/azure-containers-deployment-operation-failed-with-status-200-resource-state

Answer (score 0):

When we consider for AKS upgrade, Always try with creating a new nodepool with the decided upgrade version to the cluster first and then drain the nodes of old nodepools . It will help you t identify the related issues and will be considered for the production upgrade process.