# Azure Containers deployment - "Operation failed with status 200: Resource State Failed"

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

From Azure we try to create container using the Azure Container Instances with prepared YAML. From the machine where we execute az container create command we can login successfully to our private registry (e.g fa-docker-snapshot-local.docker.comp.dev on **JFrog Artifactory** ) after entering password and we can docker pull it as well

```
docker login fa-docker-snapshot-local.docker.comp.dev -u svc-faselect
Login succeeded
```

So we can pull it successfully and the image path is the same like when doing manually docker pull:

```
   image: fa-docker-snapshot-local.docker.comp.dev/fa/ads:test1
```

We have YAML file for deploy, and trying to create container using the az command from the SAME server. In the YAML file we have set up the same registry information: server, username and password and the same image

```
az container create --resource-group FRONT-SELECT-NA2 --file ads-azure.yaml
```

When we try to execute this command, it takes for 30 minutes and after that message is displayed: "Deployment failed. Operation failed with status 200: Resource State Failed"

Full Yaml:

```
apiVersion: '2019-12-01'
location: eastus2
name: ads-test-group
properties:
  containers:
  - name: front-arena-ads-test
    properties:
      image: fa-docker-snapshot-local.docker.comp.dev/fa/ads:test1
      environmentVariables:
        - name: 'DBTYPE'
          value: 'odbc'
      command:
      - /opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start
      - ads_start
      - '-unicode'
      - '-db_server test01'                        
      - '-db_name HEDGE2_ADM_Test1'                        
      - '-db_user sqldbadmin'                              
      - '-db_password pass'                   
      - '-db_client_user HEDGE2_ADM_Test1'                
      - '-db_client_password Password55'                
      ports:
      - port: 9000
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 4
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /opt/front/arena/host
        name: ads-filesharevolume
  imageRegistryCredentials: # Credentials to pull a private image
  - server: fa-docker-snapshot-local.docker.comp.dev
    username: svcacct-faselect
    password: test
  ipAddress:
    type: Private
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: '9000'
  volumes:
  - name: ads-filesharevolume
    azureFile:
      sharename: azurecontainershare
      storageAccountName: frontarenastorage
      storageAccountKey: kdUDK97MEB308N=
  networkProfile:
    id: /subscriptions/746feu-1537-1007-b705-0f895fc0f7ea/resourceGroups/SELECT-NA2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkProfiles/fa-aci-test-networkProfile
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: Always
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Can you please help us why this error occurs?
Thank you

Comment: Could you please share your ads-azure.yaml?

Comment: Can you share more details about the error? And if the network file already exists before you deploy this docker-compose file?

Comment: @CharlesXu Hi Charles, unfortunately that is the only info which I can see in the log, nothing else. I searched for some similar issues, related to core quota limits but I don't thinks that's the case now. Network Profile exists - Admin had to create it manually. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge, there is nothing wrong with your YAML file, I only can give you some possible reasons.

1. Make sure the configurations are all right, the server URL, username, and password, also include the image name and tag;
2. Change the port from `'9000' into` 9000``, I mean remove the double quotes;
3. Take a look at the [Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files), maybe the mount volume makes a crash to the container. Then you need to mount the file share to a new folder, I mean the new folder that does not exist before.

Comment: could you be please so kind to assist me on this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66037883/kubernetes-mount-volume-failed-when-trying-to-deploy  thanks

Comment: I will send my Azure Admins these instructions and I hope they will re-try creation based on these instructions... Thanks!

Comment: @AndreyDonald Any updates on this question? Does the answer solve it?

Comment: yes. I marked as answer thank you very much. The issue was in wrong configuration with one of the arguments. Will you be able maybe to assist me with one issue which blocks our implementation... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190275/kubernetes-ingress-controller-cannot-tcp-connect-from-outside-virtual-machine

Comment: @AndreyDonald That's great. Well, I will take a look at your new issue.